# Creating mod_rewrite rule with one GET variable regardless of url-level

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, getparameter

I'm trying to get this scenario to work:

URL: www.domain.com/sub/level/details/123/
Should be processed as: www.domain.com/sub/level/?product=123

"sub" and "level" can vary. It could also be /foo/doo/details/1/ or with even more sublevels: /foo/bar/foo/bar/foo/details/123/

Only the part: "/details/" followed by an integer/id isn't changing.

I tried and modified the .htaccess file from an older TYPO3 installation:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$  http://test.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^fileadmin/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3conf/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^./details/([0-9]+)/$ ?product=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

I would be very grateful for your support!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect as your matching a single character at start before `/detail/`.

Replace this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^./details/([0-9]+)/$ ?product=$1
```

With this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/details/(\d+)/?$ $1?product=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```